# Create a stored procedure to display last names

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure to display the last name as "Name" from the employee table for a specific department. The requirement is as below:

```
The name of the procedure     : EmployeesDept
Name of the argument as input : DeptNo
```

I am trying to use the following syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Employeesdept(@Deptno char)
AS
    DECLARE 
BEGIN
    SELECT lastname AS name
    FROM employee
    WHERE workdept = @Deptno
END
GO

EXECUTE Employeesdept @Deptno
GO
```

But I don't know why the procedure is not working.

Comment: where is your code .In Sql server on mysql which one?

Comment: Sql server code (which this is) won't even syntax in mysql.and what do you mean by not working? Do you get an error or simply not get anything returned. AND you aren't passing a value to the procedure for the dept you want.AND you have a DECLARE with no variabe definition..

Comment: And char without a length truncates to 1 character.

Comment: thanks with just your hint I am able to figure out what problem was I haven't add length to char.

Answer (score 4):

Much better then procedure is [Table Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#TVF) (TVF).

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Employeesdept 
(  
    @Deptno varchar(30)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT lastname as name
        from employee
        where workdept=@Deptno
```

Big advantage is that TVF return Table, therefore you can use it in other queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employeesdept('your_dept_no')
```

You don't want to use procedures for data selection, but for data transformation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE Employeesdept(@Deptno CHAR(100))
AS
Begin
SELECT lastname as name
from employee
where workdept=@Deptno
end
go
```

`EXECUTE YOUR PROCEDURE`

```
exec [dbo].[Employeesdept] @Deptno=VALUE
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE  PROCEDURE Employeesdept(@Deptno char(3))
as
Begin
SELECT lastname as Name
from employee
where workdept=@Deptno
end
go
```

Comment: I suspect `char(3)` only "works" for specific department values since 3 characters seems very small for the actual domain. Don't start learning bad habits. The datatype of the parameter should match the datatype of the associated column.